# Is Microsoft Sql Server 2014 certified for Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to update so version of my machine where is installed Microsoft Sql Server 2014, is this certified for Windows Server 2016? I don't want problems with MS assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's supported.

Here you can find the full compatibility matrix: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find 2016 in "Server Core Support:" but only in Principal Editions, is it important this difference?

Comment: Only if you want to use the Server Core edition of Windows (the version without a GUI and with only command-line management).

Comment: If you don't even know what that means, then no, it's not important :)